# Javascript OOP and Class

Tags: javascript

The code is here:

```
Father.js

(function(){
function father(){

};
father.prototype.init = function(){
    console.log('father');
}
})()

Child.js

(function(){
function child(){

}

child.prototype.init = function(){
    console.log('child');
}

var father = new father();
 })()
```

I have 2 questions:
How can I call father object or child object between script tag or any third javascript files that I create ?
Second: how can I call the father object inside child class. 
I am new to JS and have some problems with OOP in javascript.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Like `var Father = (function(){...; return Father }());`

Comment: @elclanrs: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should assign the result of the anonymous function to a variable that way you can use it without leaking what's inside of the IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), thus encapsulating everything but the constructor:

```
var Father = (function(){

  // Private stuff...

  function Father(){}

  Father.prototype.something = function(){};

  return Father; // Public constructor
}());
```

Now you can use `Father` in your `Child` class, or better yet, use the same pattern but pass the parent class as parameter to the IIFE:

```
var Child = (function(_parent){

  function Child() {
    _parent.apply(this, arguments); // inherit properties from Parent class
  }

  Child.prototype = Object.create(_parent.prototype); // inherit Parent prototype

  Child.prototype.something = function(){};

  return Child;
}(Father));
```

Comment: That is what exactly I am looking for. Thank you very much for all the answers.

Comment: Note that Object.create isn't supported in older browsers (IE 8) and has Child.prototype.constructor point to the wrong object. This could be of value if you plan to use `this.constructor` at some point in Child intances.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question one is you define father and child in the global scope:

```
function father(){
};
father.prototype.init = function(){
    console.log('father');
}
function child(){
}
child.prototype.init = function(){
    console.log('child');
}
// can't name your var father because it'll overwrite the father function
var dad = new father();
```

You can use namespacing to restrict the amounts of variables in the global scope:

in father.js:

```
var myApp=myApp || {};
myApp.father=...
```

in child.js:

```
var myApp=myApp || {};
myApp.child=...
var dad = new myApp.father();
```

To call father object in child you can do `father.call(this);` making all the father properies in the father function defined as `this.someprop=...` part of the just created child. If you just want to access the father instance named dad (see code above) then you can do `dad.init()`

More on inheritance and prototype here:

[Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)

Comment: If I do that, how can I include jQuery inside class ? Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: You add jQuery as the first file and you can use $ in any other included files.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/J75Zz/

It doesn't matter on how many .js files you "distribute" your code, it's just "one code block", which get's executed (well, almost ...).

You should name Objects with Capitals, there's already a clash between object `father` and variable `father`.

Comment: Note that Child doesn't overload Father's init function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading and it doesn't technically override it either because Child doesn't have Father as prototype (didn't inherit init from Father in the first place)

Comment: From my fiddle: Yes, but is the overloading requested by OP? Q was **Second: how can I call the father object inside child class** and I understand that as a simple instantiation of object child within father? Answer to that was already given.